# Hide Custom Script Gizmo In Scene Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scene

From Unity Manual:

> *Unity allows you to assign custom icons for GameObjects and scripts. These icons display in the Scene view, along with built-in icons for items such as Lights and Cameras. Use the [Gizmos menu](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.3/Documentation/Manual/GizmosMenu.html) to control how icons are drawn in the Scene view.*

This icon is also displayed in the Scene View As Shown. But if multiple objects have the script and are closer together the scene view looks like a mess, especially in the 2D gizmos view:

[image: upload_2022-12-25_15-22-28.png]

How can I remove the icon from the scene view and keep it in the inspector and project window?

I have tried using the [`GizmoUtility.SetGizmoEnabled`](https://docs.unity3d.com/2022.2/Documentation/ScriptReference/GizmoUtility.SetGizmoEnabled.html) function. But it didn't work!

Comment: Hide the gizmo using the menu?

Comment: I want to automate it. I am shipping this product. I don't want the users to hide the gizmo manually.

Comment: Funnily enough, I am having the same issue right now and stumbled upon your question, which is brand new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to solve this issue myself for some time, and It seems the only way to automate disabling the script icon gizmo is by disabling the icon gizmos of your specific `MonoBehaviour` through reflection.

Here's where I found my solution. The last answer by Acegikmo gives a concise method that solves the issue perfectly.
https://answers.unity.com/questions/851470/how-to-hide-gizmos-by-script.html

```
static MethodInfo setIconEnabled;
static MethodInfo SetIconEnabled => setIconEnabled = setIconEnabled ??
    Assembly.GetAssembly( typeof(Editor) )
    ?.GetType( "UnityEditor.AnnotationUtility" )
    ?.GetMethod( "SetIconEnabled", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic );
 
public static void SetGizmoIconEnabled( Type type, bool on ) {
    if( SetIconEnabled == null ) return;
    const int MONO_BEHAVIOR_CLASS_ID = 114; // https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ClassIDReference.html
    SetIconEnabled.Invoke( null, new object[] { MONO_BEHAVIOR_CLASS_ID, type.Name, on ? 1 : 0 } );
}
```

You just need to call the method `SetGizmoIconEnabled` from anywhere for the Type of your `MonoBehaviour` and it should work.

---

The alternative is to manually find the Gizmo dropdown menu in the Scene view and disable the script Gizmo from there:

[image]